# Why is parseFloat('1/2') == 1 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am unable to understand this:

```
parseFloat('1/2') == 1 Not Expected
parseFloat(1/2) == 0.5 Expected
parseFloat('0.5') == 0.5 Expected
parseFloat(0.5) == 0.5 Expected
```

Is it some issue or am I doing something wrong? Also, how to get

```
parseFloat('1/2') == 0.5
```

Comment: `'1/2'` is a string

Comment: `parseFloat` is not `eval`.

Comment: `1/2` is not a float, it's a mathematical operation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As in doc mentioned [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

> parseFloat parses its argument, and returns a floating point number. If it encounters a character other than a sign (+ or -), numeral (0-9), a decimal point, or an exponent, it returns the value up to that point and ignores that character and all succeeding characters. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

so `1/2` treated as a string.
Not only that - this string does not contain a valid number representation in JavaScript.

Numbers in JavaScript may include `-`, `0-9`, `.` and `+e`.
`/` is not a part of it. Therefore - `parseFloat` parses all the characters that are legal as a number - which in your case is just the `1` part, and ignores rest.

`1/2` in JavaScript is not a number, but an expression including 2 numbers and an operator (`1` = num, `/` = operator, `2` = number). What can execute expressions?

You can use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to calculate fractional form.

```js
console.log(eval('2/3'))
```

Mind that `eval` is a dangerous function: using `eval` on user-input can lead to exploits.

Comment: Agreed, but if I want to use a polynomial as a string is it not possible.

Comment: @ShubhenduVaid you need to evaluate first using `eval()`, then can use.

Answer (score 6):

`parseFloat` does not understand the `/` character as a division nor does it do an `eval` of the string input.

It simply stops looking when it encounters the character it doesn't understand and returns the correctly parsed first part:

```js
console.log(
  parseFloat("1/2"), // 1
  parseFloat("3/2"), // 3
  parseFloat("1kahsdjfjhksd2") // 1
)
```

If you do want to evaluate the string `"1/2"` to the number `0.5`, you can use `eval`. Be careful, because using `eval` can be a [security risk, slow and hard to debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea).

```js
console.log(
  eval("1/2")
);
```

Comment: Agreed, but if I want to use a polynomial as a string is it not possible.

Comment: You can use `eval("1/2")`, but you should research the [pitfalls of using `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) and decide for yourself if it's worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Your parsing a string that will be converted to 1. If your string was only numbers (e.g. "0.5") them they would be converted correctly, but as it includes the '/', the automatic type conversion will not occur and it will remain as a string. When using numbers the expected behavior occurs, that is:

```
parseFloat(1/2) === 0.5 // true
```

Comment: This is true, but if you're already working with numbers there's no reason to call `parseFloat()` at all. In fact doing that will convert the number to a string first and then convert it back.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure. but if you play around with parseFloat a bit you will see that it tries to convert every number it finds to a float, but stops as soon as there is a unexpected value so :

```
parseFloat('1/asdf') == 1
```

but

```
parseFloat('0.5') == 0.5
```

So parse float does not calculate for you, but just parses every number it finds, until there is something non numerical.